# How do I make this menu + dropdown button responsive?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

I've been trying to make my nav (including the "works" dropdown button) responsive by making them appear through the usual three parallel lines on the top right margin that would then display what I've written on the nav bar when clicked from a mobile.

I've been trying for about two hours without a decent result. 
I'm pretty sure it's not the hardest thing but I can't seem to get it right. Would love to understand how it works. Here's the desktop size, non-responsive navbar.

Here's the html:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>AURORA CATERA -- 2020 ALL RIGHT RESERVED</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel='icon' href='FAVICON.jpg' type='image/x-icon'/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="img/AURORA-YLOW-FIN.png" alt="logo"></a></div>


    <div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">ALL</a></li>
        <div class="dropdown">
         <button class="dropbtn">STUFF ▾</button>
             <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">PHOTOS</a>
                <a href="#">VIDEOS</a>
                 <a href="posters.html">POSTERS</a>
  </div>
</div>
        <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/auroracatera" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></li></i></a>
    </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the CSS:

```
.wrapper{
    width: 100%;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
}

.header{
    padding: 5px 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}


.header img{
    max-height: 400px;
    max-width: 550px;
    margin-left: 60px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}


.menu{
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    top: -85px;
    left: 0px;
    margin-right: 70px;
}
.menu ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 28px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.menu ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#F8E315;
    font-family: Rajdhani, "sanf serif";
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

.menu ul li a:hover{
    color:#C7C7C7;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: black;
  color: #F8E315;
  padding: 14px;
  font-family: Rajdhani, "sans-serif";
  font-size: 15px;
  border: none;
}

.dropbtn:hover{
    color: #c7c7c7;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
 float: left;
}


.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: #F8E315;
  font-family: Rajdhani, "sans-serif";
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: #c7c7c7;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: So if the display size has reached a certain size, the menu list should disappear and the 3 lines should appear. from a certain size?

Comment: @SwissCodeMen yes, precisely. So that when you click on the three lines the elements in the nav bar will appear in a vertical order

Comment: I can try tomorrow, but it is very difficult to dropdown an existing menu list.  I would solve it with bootstrap4 anyway. but we will see

Answer (score 0):

A basic burger-menu can be achieved by doing the following steps:

1) Create a  with the class of burger-menu as a previous sibling element of the navigation you want to hide on mobile screen width.
   a) You dont want this to show on your desktop medias, so in the css, style it as `display: none;`

2) Create a media query for the desired device. Let's say 480px for a mobile device.

3) Within this media query, style the navigation that you want to appear on hover (or click) as `display: none;`

4) Within this media query, style your burger-menu. In my example, I've styled something very basic, for time reasons, but you can research using spans to make a responsive burger menu.

5) Within this media query, declare an on hover pseudo-class for your burger-menu which accesses the hidden navigation. Since you placed the burger-menu as a the previous sibling element of your navigation, you can use the `+` css rule to target it like so

```
.burger-menu:hover + .menu {

}
```

This means that, when you hover over the burger-menu, you will affect the css of .menu. You can place how .menu's styles will be affected in the above CSS selector.

Here is a basic example of how this process works with your code.

Add this to your html, before your `.menu <div>`

```
<div class="burger-menu"></div>
    <div class="menu">
```

Add this to your css file, at the bottom

```
.burger-menu {
  display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .burger-menu {
    display: block;
    background-color: white;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
  }
  .burger-menu:hover + .menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Typically, you would advance this by using `toggleClass` with JQuery to add and remove display to your navigation menu on clicking the burger menu.

P.s the benefit of using spans to create your burger-menu will be when you want it to have nice animation, changing from a burger menu to a cross, or arrow, etc.

Comment: I've decided that instead of using JQuery it was just best to remove the dropdown button and to rely solely on fairly "basic" html and CSS to obtain a burger menu.

Comment: Yeah, it did. Now I can't seem to move my flexbox underneath my header but I'll try to figure it out

Comment: What's your new code? If you have codesandbox I can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution with a responsive menu list. Now you should add this menu list to your project.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
body {margin:0;font-family:Arial}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.menu li{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 28px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.topnav a{
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;    
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a, li {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
 <a href="index.html">ALL</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">STUFF ▾</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
               <a href="#">PHOTOS</a>
               <a href="#">VIDEOS</a>
               <a href="posters.html">POSTERS</a>
            </div>
        </div>
     <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
     <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
     <a href="https://www.instagram.com/auroracatera" target="_blank">         <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
     </a>
     <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    
</div>
```

I hope you can do something with it and add it to your project ...